# automatically remove wildcard files when they exist

Tags: makefile

I'm running `watch make` and I want to automatically remove `*~` files on `make`.

I've tried:

```
all: clean

clean:
    rm *~
```

But, it annoyingly gives an error after `*~` have been successfully removed:

```
rm: cannot remove `*~': No such file or directory
```

I just want it to be silent if there are no files to be cleaned. How do I make it silent in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the effects of [`rm`'s `-f` flag](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) is to suppress diagnostics due to non-existent files.

According to POSIX, `-f` also prevents `rm`'s exit status being affected by non-existent files, but (presumably) historically this has not been the case everywhere, so makefile *clean* rules typically use `-` in front of the `rm` command to have make ignore any non-zero exit status just in case:

```
clean:
    -rm -f *~
```